# How round (395,-2) works in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I executed `round(395,-2)` and it returned `400` as a output.How this thing worked.?

Comment: Take a look: https://bugs.python.org/issue5473

Comment: @RafaelC That does not apply to this

Comment: I'm curious what you expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended. A negative value will round to a power of 10. -1 rounds to the nearest 10, -2 to the nearest 100, etc. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round

Answer (score 4):

In the example you provided, `round(395, -2)` means *round 395 to the nearest hundred*.

The function `round` takes the precision you want as second argument. Negative precision means you want to remove significative digits *before* the decimal point.

```
round(123.456, 3)  # 123.456
round(123.456, 2)  # 123.45
round(123.456, 1)  # 123.4
round(123.456, 0)  # 123.0
round(123.456, -1) # 120.0
round(123.456, -2) # 100.0
round(123.456, -3) # 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
round(number[, ndigits]) -> floating point number
```

Round a number to a given precision in decimal digits (default 0 digits).
This always returns a floating point number.  Precision may be negative. When its negative it rounds off to the **power of 10**, here its `-2` and it will round off to `100`. so `395` will be round off to nearest `100` which is `400`.

Different ways to round off

Use the built-in function round():

```
round(1.2345,2)
1.23
```

Or built-in function format():

```
format(1.2345, '.2f')
'1.23'
```

Or new style string formatting:

```
"{:.2f}".format(1.2345)
'1.23
```

Or old style string formatting:

```
"%.2f" % (1.679)
'1.68'
```