# Replace values inside list by generic numbers to group and reference for statistical computing

Tags: pandas, numpy

I usually use `"${:,.2f}". format(prices)` to round numbers before commas, but what I'm looking for is different, I want to change values numbers to group them and reference them by mode:

Let say I have this list:

> 0        34,123.45
>
> 1        34,456.78
>
> 2        34,567.89
>
> 3        33,222.22
>
> 4        30,123.45

And the replace function will turn the list to:

> 0        34,500.00
>
> 1        34,500.00
>
> 2        34,500.00
>
> 3        33,200.00
>
> 4        30,100.00

Like this when I use `stats.mode(prices_rounded)` it will show as a result:

> Mode Value = 34500.00
>
> Mode Count = 3

Is there a conversion function already available that does the job? I did search for days without luck...

> EDIT - WORKING CODE:

```
#create list
df3 = df_array
print('########## df3: ',df3)

#convert to float
df4 = df3.astype(float)
print('########## df4: ',df4)

#convert list to string
#df5 = ''.join(map(str, df4))
#print('########## df5: ',df5)

#round values
df6 = np.round(df4 /100) * 100
print('######df6',df6)

#get mode stats
df7 = stats.mode(df6)
print('######df7',df7)

#get mode value
df8 = df7[0][0]
print('######df8',df8)

#convert to integer
df9 =  int(df8)  
print('######df9',df9)
```

This is exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: It will be much appreciated if you can explain why you gave -1 to this question instead of just ghost tagging?
I'm stuck and looking for answers...

Comment: didn't downvote but why *34,123.45* gets converted to *34,500* and what exactly is your expected output; what do you mean by *I want to change values numbers to group them and reference them by mode*? Are you looking for a single scalar output or ...?

Comment: @MustafaAydın , I want to create a recurrent target price history so I can build resistance and support prices assumptions when making investments decisions

Comment: Okay then, I don't know what those mean but that's my lack of knowledge. Perhaps someone else can help.

Comment: @MustafaAydın ,no worries, but there is no function available that converts 1234 to 1200? That's all I'm looking for (then apply it to a list)

Comment: Answer below seems to do that, doesn't it? Alternatively `round(1234, -2)` also seems to work. For negative argument to `round`, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50572048/9332187).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
>>> sr
0    34123.45  # <- why 34500.00?
1    34456.78
2    34567.89  # <- why 34500.00?
3    33222.22
4    30123.45
dtype: float64

>>> np.round(sr / 100) * 100
0    34100.0
1    34500.0
2    34600.0
3    33200.0
4    30100.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: it says ``TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`` so I added `np.round(float(df4) /100) * 100` but now it says ``ValueError: could not convert string to float: `` with the list of values

Comment: Convert your series/columns to float: `sr.astype(float)`

Comment: ok I did progress, I tried `sr.replace(',', '')` to remove the dots (I updated the code above and added the terminal log) but I get ``AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace'`` working on fixing it now.